# Understanding HikariCP/JDBC driver classnames vs data source classnames

Tags: java, jdbc, hikaricp

In HikariCP (and JDBC, really), what's the difference between setting a *driver class name and JDBC URL* versus setting a *data source class name and URL property*?

I ask because I'm integrating [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) and based on what I've found, I need to define the p6spy driver as a driver class name, but when I'm using a database directly (MySQL, MariaDB, H2, etc) I defined them as data sources:

```java
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setDriverClassName("com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver");
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:p6spy:mysql://localhost/test");
```

```java
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource");
config.addDataSourceProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
```

Am I losing functionality by using the first approach? What's the end result difference between these two definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one case the connection is created through `java.sql.DriverManager` (or maybe even directly using the `java.sql.Driver` implementation), and you can only use the configuration properties the driver supports that way.

When using a data source, you're using an implementation of `javax.sql.DataSource`, and can only use the configuration properties the data source supports that way. If we're talking about driver-provided `DataSource` implementations, there generally is no difference. They usually offer the same (or similar) configuration properties, and produce exactly the same connection as they would return through their `Driver` implementation.

In theory, using a `DataSource` can have some benefits because of its programmatic configuration (instead of using properties in the URL or `Properties` object), and the fact you could have the `DataSource` sourced from some external configuration through JNDI or other means.

However, when configured through HikariCP, and specifically in the way as shown in your question, there is no substantial difference.